# How to choose a specific msvcr.dl in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I would like to use an old msvcr71.dll when compiling Nim.

Is there a way to do so? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the manual, [right here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#foreign-function-interface-dynlib-pragma-for-import). As StackOverflow doesn't like link responses, a copy-paste:

```
proc imported_proc(): ReturnType
  {.cdecl, dynlib: "msvcr71.dll", importc.}
```

This asumes there is a function in `msvcf71.dll` called `imported_proc` that you want to wrap in your Nim code without changing the name.

You can also tweak which libraries to load when compiling, as explained [here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#dynliboverride):

```
$ nim c --dynlibOverride:msvcr71 --passL:msvcr71.dll program.nim
```

Didn't test any of the code, hope it helps. You can always try to find some code that does this kind of linking, for example https://github.com/khchen/wNim/blob/master/wNim/private/winimx.nim or maybe https://github.com/brentp/hts-nim/blob/master/src/hts/private/hts_concat.nim